# Java Website not allowing me to download the installer

Tags: macos, mac, java, macbook, macos-bigsur

I recently have been attempting to install java from the [oracle website](https://java.com/en/download/) and though I have refreshed, reopened, restarted my computer as well as the browser, I have found no success in installing java whatsoever. Any help is appreciated, as I am at a loss for what I should do here. MacBook Pro, Intel Core i7 Model Big Sur Version 11.6 There is no error message upon install, and I can install other applications as well. The website seemingly hangs, and eventually just does not load when I attempt to install. No error message or anything.

When I say hang, I mean the following:
I press download on the website provided, nothing changes and the page loads until my web browser states that it has "Failed to open page", stating that the webpage is not responding. This has been happening for close to a week. (The installer is never downloaded)

Comment: We need much more detail - precise model of Mac, current OS, what was the error message...

Comment: Apologies -- I did not realize this was not included in the original comment.

MacBook Pro, Intel Core i7 Model
Big Sur Version 11.6

There is no error message upon install, and I can install other applications as well. The website seemingly hangs, and eventually just does not load when I attempt to install. No error message or anything.

Comment: Note: I was able to install other things such as RuneScape and files online, java just does not seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "website seemingly hangs, and eventually just does not load" - all that site does is download an installer. Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1680777/edit) your question to add clarification, don't just put it in comments.

Comment: I believe I've added all the background information :)

Comment: So, the issue would seem to be you cannot get the website to load, not that you can't install Java. You never get the installer at all.

Comment: I've changed the title to be more precise to that issue -- do you know any possible solutions/issues that could be causing this?

Comment: You have tried [this](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) page right?  The page you linked to only offered the Windows version. Is there a reason you are trying to install Java 8 instead of a newer version?

Comment: Yes sir, I have attempted to download it using that page as well. When I click the download. Also, where would I go to get the newer version? I apologize, I am ignorant on where to find the newer editions. I'm not sure if the issue is because I am attempting download an older version.

Comment: @Ramhound - the page is browser/OS-sensitive. It offered me the correct version for my Mac. According to that Oracle page, the latest version is v8.301 -  "Recommended Version 8 Update 301 (filesize: 83.05 MB)
Release date July 20, 2021" OP's issue seems to be that they simply cannot access the page… might be DNS/firewall or something further up the line, ISP etc. Impossible to tell.

Comment: Download java from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

What browsers have you tried using? If it doesn't work with one browser, try another. Otherwise, here is a direct link to the latest Java installer for macOS. Hope this helps! :) https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=245470_4d5417147a92418ea8b615e228bb6935